# React - Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Firebase cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

while using Firebase Auth in React I got this in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Firebase cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Recompose.esm.js:803:1
    at Module../src/components/globalPages/SignUp/index.js (index.js:113:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/constants/routes.js (index.js:119:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/components/App/index.js (bundle.js:15:75)
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './components/App/index';
import Firebase, {
  FirebaseContext
} from './components/Firebase';
ReactDOM.render( < React.StrictMode > < FirebaseContext.Provider value = {
  new Firebase()
} > < App / > < /FirebaseContext.Provider> </React.StrictMode > , document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals();
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
  }
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  signOut = () => firebase.auth().signOut();
  passwordReset = email => firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  passwordUpdate = password => firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(password);
};
export default Firebase;
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './components/App/index';
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
      <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();

Comment: class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
  }
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  signOut = () => 
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  passwordReset = email => 
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  passwordUpdate = password =>
    firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(password);
};

export default Firebase;

Comment: Don't paste code in comments, edit  your question.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear that this is not a valid API call: `new Firebase()`. What do you expect that line to do? If you remove the line, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

The above code was giving error, Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Firebase cannot be invoked without 'new', In my case,

so this is what I did

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

just add "new" keyword. It worked for me, hope this helps